# How do I make text from an textbox send to the user's wall with facebook's android sdk?

Tags: android, facebook

I have a login system working well and most things are working smoothly. However, the user has to press a button that says "post", which then pops up a screen (similar to the browser) where they can type it up. I want to implement a way for them to type a post into a textbox in my main activity and then press a button which will post it to their facebook wall. Is this possible? I have the facebook sdk for android already.

Comment: are u using Facebook SDK ?

Comment: yes, I've been using the facebook sdk. I just don't understand how to implement a way for the text of a textbox to be sent to the user's wall without going through the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have used this:

```
bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", msg);
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

if(session != null){
Toast.makeText(context, "Posting...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {             
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
        if (error != null) {                    
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Post", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Posted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     }
  };
  Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", bundle, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

  RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);            
  task.execute();
}
```

this is technique, using Graph-Api. using Graph-Api u can only post to user's wall (without openning a browser or a webview). if u try to post on user's friend wall it will fail.

Comment: I have an "onComplete" method that is called when the person says "post" on the webview form. I'm not sure where I should be implementing your code. I get an error saying that "public void onCompleted(Response response)" is a duplicate method... and I get "context cannot be resolved to a type".... thanks again.

Comment: just create a method like `public void poststory(){}` , and then paste above code into it. then in your webview onComplete method just call the `poststory()` method. if you r writting this code in an actvity, replace `context` with `getApplicationContext()`, or if it is in a fragment then replace with `getActivity()`. @ThatGuyThere